# MySQL create function fails

Tags: mysql, sql, function

This

```
CREATE FUNCTION getTagID(tag VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS BIGINT

BEGIN
DECLARE tagID BIGINT;
            SET tagID = (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE text = tag);
IF tagID IS NULL
THEN
            (INSERT INTO tags (text) VALUES (tag));
            SET tagID = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
END IF;
RETURN tagID;
END
```

fails with

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Why?

This function is related to the problem here:

[mysql insert if not exists on joined tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519975/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-on-joined-tables/15526382?noredirect=1#15526382)

Comment: Have you set delimiter to something different from `;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the `DELIMITER` and remove the parenthesis around the `INSERT` statement.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getTagID(tag VARCHAR(100)) 
RETURNS BIGINT
BEGIN
    DECLARE tagID BIGINT;
    SET tagID = (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE text = tag);
    IF tagID IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO tags (text) VALUES (tag); -- don't put inside parenthesis
        SET tagID = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
    END IF;
    RETURN tagID;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: that seems to work and you are the hero of my day... but could you explain what's the matter with "DELIMITER"?

Comment: `DELIMITER` changes the termination  symbol on the query and allowing you to execute multiple statements that contains `;`. Remember that every after `;` closes the statement that is why when changing to another symbol allows you to execute multiple statement without breaking it.

Answer (score 2):

Type to set delimiter to `;;` like this:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE FUNCTION getTagID(tag VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS BIGINT
BEGIN
  DECLARE tagID BIGINT;
  SET tagID = (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE text = tag);
  IF tagID IS NULL
  THEN
    INSERT INTO tags (text) VALUES (tag);
    SET tagID = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
  END IF;
  RETURN tagID;
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Delimiter is used by MySQL client (not sever) to split input into separate queries.  Default delimiter is `;` so MySQL client sent the following query to the server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getTagID(tag VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS BIGINT

BEGIN
DECLARE tagID BIGINT
```

Which is incomplete and thus incorrect.