# MySql db optimization number of columns in a table

Tags: mysql

I'm "designing" a mySql table and I got 32 columns that I think could be a little bit too much. 
There are 9 numeric fields (int,tinyint,smallint), 17 varchar, 2 datetime, 4 Text. All the string are in utf8_unicode_ci collation.

Is it too much? Any advice?

Comment: Hard to tell without the column names and content.

Comment: some of the fields don't have a descriptive title unfortunately I have n't actually create the original project. I can tell that there are 4 different fields varchar for the name in 4 differents languages and the same for the description (Text), 4 description for 4 languages. 4 tinyint fields are for the categories (each element can belong to 4 different categories).

Comment: What does "too much" mean?  What are you afraid is going to happen by adding too many columns?  Bad query performance?

Comment: Database performance basically. There won't be many records in the beginnig (27.000 roughly) but the number will increase by the end of 2014 so I don't want to find myself dealing with db performance problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 4 tinyint fields are for the categories (each element can belong to 4 different categories)

This sounds like [repeating groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951285/db-design-1st-normal-form-and-repeating-groups). That's one deficiency with respect to relational database design.

The same probably applies to the 4 names and 4 descriptions. Every one-to-many relationship should have a subordinate table.

I can't tell from your description if there are other parts of this design that are not normalized.
But I would guess there are.

There are some legitimate reasons to break rules of normalization, but like any optimization, they should be done to optimize *specific queries*.

In the absence of any context of a set of queries, go with a normalized design, because it optimizes for avoiding data redundancy and preventing anomalies, and for supporting the broadest range of query types.