# read from registry and import into database

Tags: c#, sql, registry, ssms, read-write

What do you guy suggest is the quickest way to read through a registry and import each folder as a row in a database.  Let's say I have 200 folders, within those folders is a bunch of registry keys, I want to make each key a column and each folder a row.  Is it better to import this as a text file from the registry first or make a program read it while in the registry (should I use c#?)?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? First, you're taking data from one database (your registry) and making a less organized copy of it. I'm thinking: [eliminate repeating groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951285/db-design-1st-normal-form-and-repeating-groups) and you're considering exactly the opposite.

Comment: We are redoing our back-end so that it no longer uses the registry.  Currently, any changes to the configuration requires a developer to make these registry changes.  We will move it to sql server and give it a front-end so that our customer service department can make these changes.